# How to enable analytics_debug.js when GA is implemented via GTM and a browser doesn't support any extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

How do I change standard analytics.js to analytics_debug.js when GA is implemented via GTM?

Debugging occurs in some specific browser without plugins/extensions support.

I know that there is a source code of google debugger chrome extension here:

https://github.com/wildskyf/Google-analytics-debugger/blob/master/background.js

But how do I implement it into site’s html or GTM custom-HTML tag so that it will change analytics.js to analytics_debug.js.

Could you help me with this code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Universal Analytics tag has a field that determines if the standard or the debug version of the code is loaded (with a default value of false):

[image]

If you set "Use debug version" to true (presumably via a variable that changes its return value between true and false, depending on some cookie or other condition) then you will get the debug output in the browser console.